# How to save nested objects in my Firebase db

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have created a view for adding categories and a view for products.  I want to add products to categories.  This is working but it would probably be more efficient to have it structed like below instead of what I've got in the screenshot.

```
products 
    - KXbMe8zo14TyOYDJh4q
          cat: {
                 id: "-KXXJY-i7Avnqw8IMqR", name: "Starters"
               }
```

Would this structure be better and how should I implement it?  I'm expecting the whole `cat` object to be passed in as I'm referening `product.cat` as the model.

If I set the `value` in the form element to be `{{cat}}` I get this in the DB:

`"{\"name\":\"Kebabs\",\"$id\":\"-KXXJl0Ice17zDIYF_Xt\",\"$priority\":null}"`

Does this look its correct?

```
<select ng-model="product.cat">
    <option ng-repeat="cat in cats" value="{{cat.$id}}">{{cat.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I'm retrieving the categories like so:

```
var cats = $firebaseArray(firebase.database().ref('category'));
cats.$loaded().then(function(){
                    $scope.cats = cats;
                });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up with the following:

```
var cats = $firebaseArray(firebase.database().ref('category'));
cats.$loaded().then(function(){
                    $scope.cats = cats;
                });

  $scope.addProduct = function() {
    console.log($scope.product);
    var category = {};

    for(var i=0; i<$scope.cats.length; i++){
        if($scope.cats[i].$id == $scope.product.catid){
            category.id = $scope.cats[i].$id;
            category.name = $scope.cats[i].name;
        }
    }

    //var record = firebase.database().ref().child('products/category').push($scope.product.cat);
    //var record = firebase.database().ref().child('products').push($scope.product);
    var record = firebase.database().ref().child('products').push({
            'category' : {id: category.id, name: category.name},
            'name' : $scope.product.name,
            'price' : $scope.product.price
        });
    if(record.key){
        $scope.productSuccess = true;
    } else {
        $scope.productSuccess = false;
    }
  };
```

This gives me the following in my DB:

[image]